# Scraping multiple pages with Scrapy and saving as a csv file

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape all the pages of Internshala and extract the Job ID, Job name, Company name and the Last date to apply and store everything in a csv to later convert to a dataframe.

```
import requests
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
import string
import pandas as pd

url='https://internshala.com/fresher-jobs'
sel=Selector(text=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content).prettify())
             
pages=sel.xpath('//span[@id="total_pages"]').xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract()
pages[0]=int(pages[0])
print(pages[0])  #which gives -> 4
```

```
class jobMan(scrapy.Spider):
    name='job'
    
    to_remove={0:["\n                ","\n               "],\
               1:['\n             ','\n            ']}
    
    def start_requests(self):
        urls="https://internshala.com/fresher-jobs/page-1"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=urls,callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self,response):
                
        ID=response.xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid individual_internship visibilityTrackerItem"]/@internshipid').extract()
        
        Job_Post = response.xpath('//div[@class="heading_4_5 profile"]/a').xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract()
        
        Company = response.xpath('//a[@class="link_display_like_text"]').xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract()
            
        Apply_By = response.xpath('//div[@class="internship_other_details_container"]/div[@class="other_detail_item_row"][2]//div[@class="item_body"]').xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract()

        for page in range(2,pages[0]+1):
            yield(scrapy.Request(url=f"https://internshala.com/fresher-jobs/page-{page}",callback=self.parse))
            
        yield {
            'ID': ID,
            'Job':Job_Post,
            'Company':Company,
            'Apply_By':Apply_By
        }
        
        
process=CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'FEED_URI':'JOBSS.csv',
    'FEED_FORMAT':'csv'
})
process.crawl(jobMan)
process.start()
```

And then finally-:

```
final=pd.read_csv('JOBSS.csv')
print(final)
```

Which gave me-:

```
   ID                                                Job  \
0 NaN  Product Developer - Science,Salesforce Develop...   
1 NaN  Business Development Manager,Mobile App Develo...   
2 NaN  Software Engineer,Social Media Strategist And ...   
3 NaN  Reactjs Developer,Full Stack Developer,Busines...   

                                             Company  \  
0  Open Door Education,Aekot Consulting And Techn...       
1  ISB Studienkolleg,TutorBin,Alphacore Technolog...       
2  CrewKarma,Internshala,Mithi Software Technolog...       
3  Startxlabs Technologies Private Limited,RavGin...       

                                            Apply_By  
0  7 Aug' 21,7 Aug' 21,7 Aug' 21,7 Aug' 21,7 Aug'...  
1  31 Jul' 21,30 Jul' 21,30 Jul' 21,31 Jul' 21,30...  
2  24 Jul' 21,24 Jul' 21,23 Jul' 21,23 Jul' 21,23...  
3  11 Jul' 21,11 Jul' 21,11 Jul' 21,11 Jul' 21,11...
```

Doubt_1-: Why is it not printing the IDs ?? I tried scraping just the ID for the first page using the same xpath and I got the correct output but not while crawling.

```
/
```

Doubt_2-: I wanted a a dataframe such that, for example, the Job_Post column contains each job post's name nested under each other (means as a new row) from all the pages merged but I am getting rows per page.

How can I solve these issues ?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

> Doubt_1-: Why is it not printing the IDs ?? I tried scraping just the ID for the first page using the same xpath and I got the correct output but not while crawling.

Because the class name has a space in it, use:

```
ID=response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "container-fluid individual_internship visibilityTrackerItem")]/@internshipid').extract()
```

Comment: ```ID=response.xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid individual_internship visibilityTrackerItem"]/@internshipid').extract()```             ```ID=response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "container-fluid individual_internship visibilityTrackerItem")]/@internshipid').extract() ```                I used the same syntax

Comment: @Intangible_pg18 Notice the word `contains`